# Show continuity of $f*(x) =\sup_{a \leq y \leq x}f(y)$ given $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$. Show the function $f^*$ defined by $f^*(x) = \sup\left\{ f(y) : a \leq y \leq x\right\}$, for  $ x \in [a,b]$, is an increasing continuous function on $[a,b]$

My approach of this is: Since $f$ is continuous, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$, therefore
$$ \forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0,x,y \in [a,b]$$
$$ |x-y| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)|<\epsilon$$ (This is the definition in Ross.)
And I would like to use this to show $f^*$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$, but I stuck when I tried to relate the uniform continuity of $f$ and the the definition of $f^*$. 
I also notice that the definition of $f^*$ implicitly implies that $f(x)\leq f^*(x)$, and there exists a $y_0$ in $[a,x]$ s.t. $f(y_0) = f^*(x)$. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You're almost there - note that if $x_1 \ge x_2$, then $\{ f(y) : a \le y \le x_2\} \subseteq \{f(y): a \le y \le x_1\}$, and thus $f^*$ is increasing by the definition of $\sup$. For continuity, note that $\sup \{f(y): a \le y \le x_1\} - \sup \{f(y): a \le y \le x_2\} \le \max \left(0, \sup\{f(y): x_1 < y \le x_2\}\right)$ (think why). Now use the uniform continuity of $f$ to show that this upper bound goes to $0$ as $x_1 \to x_2$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks, but I still don't understand how we can use that to show the uniform continuity of $f^*$ because in order to show that we need find such $\delta$, which only depends on $\epsilon$ and satisfies $\sup\{f(y): x_1 < y <= x_2\} < \epsilon$ then how do we obtain that ?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I was too hasty in typing that out. The bound should be $\max( 0, \sup \{ f(y) : x_2 < y \le x_1\} - f(x_2))$. If the $2^{nd}$ case holds, we have $\sup_{[x_2, x_1]} f(y) > f(x_2)$. Now, if $x_2$ is close enough to $x_1$, then (by unif. cont.) $\forall y\in[x_1, x_2], f(y) < f(x_1) + \epsilon/2$, so $ \sup_{[x_2, x_1]}  f(y) \le f(x_1) + \epsilon/2$. Note that we also have $f(x_1) < f(x_2) + \epsilon /2$...

Comment: (contd.) Summarising, we get $f(x_2) \le \sup_{[x_2, x_1]} f(y) \le f(x_2) + \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we're done (NB - this technically only shows one sided continuity, but should be easily to generalise)

Comment: Sorry I actually don't see how it works.. why is the bound be $\sup\{f(y):x_2 < y \leq x_1\}-f(x_2)$ and how is that related to the thing I want to show.. eventually I need to obtain that $f^*$ is uniformly continuous or continuous, that is to say, I basically need to find a $\delta$ such that the definition of continuity works.

Comment: Well, $[a,x_1] = [a,x_2] \cup (x_2, x_1]$, so $\sup_{[a,x_1]} f = \max \left( \sup_{[a,x_2]} f, \sup_{[a,x_1]} f \right)$. As for the rest, if you read through the 2nd set of comments, that's precisely what I'm trying to do there.