Help with proving that a function is increasing and continuous
I'm working on an exercise and could use some guidance. The problem is as follows:
Let $f$ be a real-valued function that is continuous on $[0,1[$. I need to show that the function $\varphi$ defined by
$$
\varphi: \begin{array}{ccc}
{[0 ; 1[ } & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{R} \\
x & \longmapsto & \sup _{0 \leqslant t \leqslant x} f(t)
\end{array}
$$
is increasing and continuous.
I've already shown that $\varphi$ is increasing. For the continuity part, I tried to show that for a point $a$ inside the interval, the function has finite left and right limits at $a$. I also thought about using the sequential characterization of continuity, and chose a monotonic sequence converging to $a_{\text {}}$ attempting to prove that its image tends to $\varphi(a)$ by using the continuity of $f$. However, I'm stuck and not sure how to proceed.
Any hints or suggestions would be really helpful!
Thanks in advance!

This is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011516/show-continuity-of-fx-sup-a-leq-y-leq-xfy-given-f-is-continuous-o but I cannot mark it as such since the answerer has ignored the site guidelines and answered in the comments.

@Medo This argument sounds rather handwavy: which continuous function are you referring to by "maximum"?

Let $x\in [0,1)$ and let $\epsilon>0$.
By the continuity of $f$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$, whenever $y\in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$.
We are going to show that $|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|<\epsilon$, whenever $y\in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$.
First, let $0\leq x<y<x+\delta$. By the continuity of $f$, we have
\begin{align}
&\phi(x)=\sup_{[0,x]}f=\max_{[0,x]}f,\\
& \phi(x)\leq \phi(y),\\
&\phi(y)=\sup_{[0,y]}f=\max_{[0,y]}f=f(x_{*}),\qquad \text{for some}\;x_{*}\in [0,y].
\end{align}
We are in one of two situations:
(1)  $x_{*}\in [0,x]$:
In this case
$$\phi(x)=\phi(y)=f(x_{*}),$$
and we have nothing to prove.
(2) $x<x_{*}\leq y$:
In this case $x<x_{*}<x+\delta$. So, by the continuity of $f$, we have
$\phi(y)=f(x_{*})<f(x)+\epsilon\leq \max_{[0,x]}f+\epsilon=\phi(x)+\epsilon$,
and we are done.

The case $x-\delta<y<x$ can be done similarly: let $\phi(x)=f(x_{*})\geq \phi(y)$.
Case 1: $x_{*}\in [0,y])$, then $\phi(y)=\phi(x)$,
Case 2: $x_{*}\in (y,x)$
$$x-\delta<y<x_{*}<x\Longrightarrow \phi(y)\leq \phi(x)=f(x_{*})<f(y)+\epsilon\leq \phi(y)+\epsilon.$$

What I write here might not be the simplest way to handle this, but I would think of it like this.
First, if $\phi$ is monotone increasing, we can prove that $\phi(x^-) = \sup \{\phi(y) : y < x\}$ and $\phi(x^+) = \inf \{\phi(y) : y > x\}$, where $\phi(x^-)$ and $\phi(x^+)$ denote left and right limits respectively (in particular, they always exist). Further, we have $\phi(x^-) \le \phi(x) \le \phi(x^+)$: from $\phi(y) \le \phi(x) \le \phi(z)$ for $y \le x \le z$ we simply take $y, z \to x$.
For $x \in (0, 1)$, $\phi$ can only be discontinuous if $\phi(x^-) < \phi(x^+)$. That is, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\phi(x^-) + \epsilon < \phi(x^+)$. Writing this out:
$$\lim_{y \to x^-} \sup_{0 \le t \le y} f(t) + \epsilon < \lim_{y \to x^+} \sup_{0 \le t \le y} f(t)$$
Since $f$ is continuous, we can pick $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon/8$ whenever $|x - y| < \delta$. Pick $y_1 < x < y_2$ with $|y_1 - y_2| < \delta$ such that:
$$\lim_{y \to x^-} \sup_{0 \le t \le y} f(t) + \epsilon \ge \sup_{0 \le t \le y_1} f(t) - \frac \epsilon 2 + \epsilon = \sup_{0 \le t \le y_1} f(t) + \frac \epsilon 2$$
and:
$$\lim_{y \to x^+} \sup_{0 \le t \le y} f(t) \le \sup_{0 \le t \le y_2} f(t) + \frac \epsilon 4$$
This is possible from the definition of the left/right limits.
Then we have:
$$\sup_{0 \le t \le y_1} f(t) + \frac \epsilon 4 \le \sup_{0 \le t \le y_2} f(t)$$
However, for $t \in (y_1, y_2]$, $f(t)$ differs from $f(y_1)$ by at most $\epsilon/8$, so the supremum can only increase by at most $\epsilon/8$ when we add these points (indeed, they might all fall under the supremum over $0 \le t \le y_1$ and it might not change at all!). But we have established that the supremum increases by at least $\epsilon/4$, contradiction.
For $x = 0$, we are instead faced with $\phi(0) < \phi(0^+)$. That is:
$$f(0) + \epsilon < \lim_{y \to 0^+} \sup_{0 \le t \le y} f(t)$$
which is analogous to the proof above ($f(0)$ differs from the limit by a positive $\epsilon$, but we can pick intervals $[0, y]$ such that the deviation of $f(t)$ from $f(0)$ should be far smaller than that).

I'd use the definition. Let $\varepsilon >0$. You need to show that exists $\delta>0$ such that $\forall x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta), x\neq a$ we have $\varphi(x)\in(\varphi(a)-\varepsilon,\varphi(a)+\varepsilon)$, let's call this set $\mathcal{U}$. Notice that $\varphi(a)=f(t_0)$ for some $t_0\in[0,a]$ (by Weierstrass theorem).
Let's consider $f(a)$, surely $f(a)\le f(t_0)$. If $f(a)<f(t_0)$, by the continuity of $f$, you can conclude that exists a $\delta >0$ such that $\varphi(x)\in\mathcal{U}$ for all $x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)$.
Hint:

  If $f(a)<f(t_0)$, then exists $\gamma:f(a)+\gamma<f(t_0)$. Also $f$ is continuous in $a$, by definition $\exists\delta >0:\forall t\in [0,1)-\{a\}, t\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)\implies f(t)\in(f(a)-\gamma,f(a)+\gamma)$ $$\displaystyle \implies\sup_{[0,a+\delta]}f(t)=f(t_0)\implies \varphi(x)\in(f(t_0)-\varepsilon,f(t_0)+\varepsilon)\;\;\forall x\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$$

If $f(a)=f(t_0)$ what you can say? Hint:

 make a similar argument, always using continuity of $f$ in $a$,  by taking a $\gamma'$ such that $f(a)+\gamma'<f(t_0)+ε$


"If $f(a)<f(t_0)$, by the continuity of $f$, you can conclude that exists a $\delta >0$ such that $\varphi(x)\in\mathcal{U}$ for all $x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)$." Explain ?

I added some suggestions, they might answer your comments too

A way, f because it is continuous in [0,1] has a maximum in $x_0$ then $\varphi (x)=f(x_0), \ if \ x \  \in [x_0,1]$, then $ \varphi $ is continuous in $(x_0,1]$ for being constant.$\varphi$ is right continuous at $x_0$ and also on the left. The reason is that $\forall \  \epsilon>0, \ \exists x_1<x_0 \ / \ \varphi(x_1)>\varphi(x_0)-\epsilon $ this is a property of the maxims, then $ \forall \ \epsilon>0, \ \exists \delta=x_0-x_1>0 \ / \ if \ \  x_0-\delta<x<x_0 \ \rightarrow |\varphi(x)-\varphi(x_0)|<\epsilon $
This because $\varphi$ is growing. Therefore $\varphi$ is continuous in $x_0$
For $x \in [0,x_0)$, the property of the maxims and the growing condition of $\varphi$ allow to demonstrate. I believe you can do it

I wanted to share the solution to the problem I posted earlier regarding the continuity of the function $\varphi$. Based on your suggestions and using the definitions of continuity, I was able to prove that the function $\varphi$ is continuous on the interval [0,1[. Here's the full reasoning:

Key Relation: $\varphi(a)=\max \left(\varphi\left(a^{-}\right), f(a)\right)$ : For any $a \in[0,1[$, we define:

$$
\varphi(a)=\sup _{0 \leq t \leq a} f(t) .
$$
Using a decreasing sequence $a_n=a-\frac{1}{n}$ converging to $a^{-}$, we observe:
$$
\varphi\left(a^{-}\right)=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \varphi\left(a_n\right)=\sup _{0 \leq t<a} f(t) .
$$
By the continuity of $f$ and the fact that $f(a)$ is achieved, we conclude that:
$$
\varphi(a)=\max \left(\varphi\left(a^{-}\right), f(a)\right) .
$$
2. Continuity from the Right: For $x>a$, we have:
$$
\varphi(x)=\max \left(\varphi(a), \sup _{a \leq t \leq x} f(t)\right)
$$
Taking the limit as $x \rightarrow a^{+}$, the continuity of $f$ guarantees that:
$$
\varphi\left(a^{+}\right)=\max (\varphi(a), f(a))
$$
Since $\varphi(a) \geq f(a)$, we obtain $\varphi\left(a^{+}\right)=\varphi(a)$. Therefore, $\varphi$ is continuous from the right.

Continuity from the Left: For $a \in] 0,1\left[\right.$, I used a decreasing sequence $a_n=a-1 / n$ with $a_n \rightarrow a^{-}$. We can show that:

$$
\varphi\left(a_n\right) \leq \varphi(a) \quad \text { and } \quad \varphi\left(a^{-}\right)=\sup _{0 \leq t<a} f(t)
$$
Finally, using the relation $\varphi(a)=\max \left(\varphi\left(a^{-}\right), f(a)\right)$, we conclude that:
$$
\varphi\left(a^{-}\right)=\varphi(a)
$$
Thus, $\varphi$ is continuous at every point in $[0,1[$.

Take $x \in [0,1)$ and set $\epsilon > 0 $. For that $\epsilon$, since $f$ is continuous, there exists a $\delta$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon$ if $ |x-y| < \delta$.
Now, note that for $\delta > t-s \geq 0$, since $\phi$ is clearly monotone,  $\phi(t) - \phi(s) \leq \phi(s) + \epsilon$. To see this, let's reason as follows: since no point in $(s-\delta,s+ \delta)$ attains values through $f$ outside $(f(s)-\epsilon,f(s) + \epsilon)$ , the maximum of $f$ in $[0,t]$ (it's a maximum since $f$ is continuous) must lie in $(\phi(s)-\epsilon,\phi(s)+ \epsilon)$.
That is, $|\phi(x)-\phi(y) |< \epsilon$ whenever $|x-y| < \delta$.
